# How to get raw output with sp_OAGetProperty

Tags: sql-server, api, ole

I am working with API calls from SQL Server and need to process a response which is something like this

```
[{"message":"Invalid attribute %fieldName = %fieldValue.","parameters":["SKU",null]},{"message":"Invalid attribute %fieldName = %fieldValue.","parameters":["SKU",null]},{"message":"Invalid attribute %fieldName = %fieldValue.","parameters":["SKU",null]}]
```

I'm trying to retrieve a response with

```
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;
```

But response is always null, how can I extract the messages?

Comment: Is the return code you store in `@ret` a 0 (success) or some other number (failure)? ref: [OLE Automation Return Codes and Error Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/ole-automation-return-codes-and-error-information)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so apparently my responseText was always null because of sp_OAGetProperty response length limitation, you need to do this instead

```
INSERT #resp ( response )
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
```